# How to refresh after inserting data into database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I am new to c#. After inserting data into my database, i have a form which allows me to view my data where the `DataGridView` would display all the data. However, the table does not display the new data that is being inserted into the database.

Have researched on `datagridview.refresh()` but its only graphical refresh.

Following is my code: *(No idea whether I'm on the right track or not)*

```
  private void button_refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //DataGridView1.refresh(); 
            //DataSet1.GetChanges();
            //TableAdapter.Fill(DataSet1.table);
        }
```

Comment: have you update the data which you have entered? and is your cell set to property readonly to false? so that you can directly select the cell and type what ever you want

Comment: Yup its checked to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using data binding then the only way is to remove all the rows:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

and then read and add rows again as you did initially

Comment: What should i do if i want to rely on data binding?

Answer (score 0):

let's imagine d is the `DataSource` I have

```
d.Add(new string[] {"a", "b", "c"});
dataGridView1.DataSource = d;
```

Now my DataGridView has **1** row

after a while ...

```
d.Add(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
d.Add(new string[] { "4", "5", "6" });
d.Add(new string[] { "x", "y", "z" });
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = d;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Now my DataGridView has 4 rows.

Comment: ah, i want the datagridtable to display all the data, with the new data as well. if i used null, nothing will be displayed. >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.Employees);
```

> `Where: Employees your table`